# Why is the mapped executable section of a static ELF not marked as file-mapped in /proc/<pid>/pagemap?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, gdb, elf

I have a gdb utility that examines the PFN of a virtual address (via `/proc/<pid>/pagemap`) and checks said PFN's flags (via `/proc/kpagecount` and `/proc/kpageflags`).

I've written & compiled a small 64-bit ELF, with 2 PT_LOAD program headers:

```
> readelf -l ./bin/a.out
Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x401000
There are 2 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000b0 0x0000b0 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000 0x00005c 0x00005c R E 0x1000

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .text
```

When looking at the mappings in gdb:

```
(gdb)  info proc mappings
process 8495
Mapped address spaces:

          Start Addr           End Addr       Size     Offset  Perms  objfile
            0x400000           0x401000     0x1000        0x0  r--p   <path-to-bin>
            0x401000           0x402000     0x1000     0x1000  r-xp   <path-to-bin>
      0x7ffff7ff9000     0x7ffff7ffd000     0x4000        0x0  r--p   [vvar]
      0x7ffff7ffd000     0x7ffff7fff000     0x2000        0x0  r-xp   [vdso]
      0x7ffffffdd000     0x7ffffffff000    0x22000        0x0  rw-p   [stack]
  0xffffffffff600000 0xffffffffff601000     0x1000        0x0  --xp   [vsyscall]
```

When checking the PFN of `0x400000`, the flags reported by `/proc/<pid>/pagemap` and `/proc/kpageflags` are as follows:

```
(gdb)  pfn 0x400000
BigEndian? 0
VADDR: 0x400000, PageSize: 4096, EntrySize: 8
Reading /proc/8495/pagemap at 0x2000
[0]0xba [1]0x5 [2]0x22 [3]0x0 [4]0x0 [5]0x0 [6]0x80 [7]0xa1
file-mapped: true, exclusively-mapped: true, soft-dirty: true, swapped: false, uffd-wp write-protected: false
Result: 0xa1800000002205ba
PFN:    0x2205ba

(gef)  kpage 0x2205ba
PFN: 0x2205ba
/proc/kpagecount: 1
Flags:
  REFERENCED
  UPTODATE
  LRU
  MMAP
```

The page is reported to be file-mapped, which I would expect, as it's the ELF file header of my executable. Doing this process on the segment with the `.text` section however, yields a different result:

```
(gdb)  pfn 0x401000
BigEndian? 0
VADDR: 0x401000, PageSize: 4096, EntrySize: 8
Reading /proc/8495/pagemap at 0x2008
[0]0xbe [1]0xb0 [2]0x27 [3]0x0 [4]0x0 [5]0x0 [6]0x80 [7]0x81
file-mapped: false, exclusively-mapped: true, soft-dirty: true, swapped: false, uffd-wp write-protected: false
Result: 0x818000000027b0be
PFN:    0x27b0be

(gdb)  kpage 0x27b0be
PFN: 0x27b0be
/proc/kpagecount: 1
Flags:
  REFERENCED
  UPTODATE
  DIRTY
  LRU
  MMAP
  ANON
  SWAPBACKED
```

I would have expected that the mapped `.text` section, which is part of my ELF file and is a segment to be loaded is also marked as file-mapped, just like the ELF file header. Why is it not?

Comment: Is it possible that gdb has written to that page the text section, causing it to be no longer backed by the file?